# How can I handle the resize of children windows when the parent windows is resized?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

So I have been trying to accomplish this for a bit now. I am having trouble handling the resize of the children windows when the parent window is resized. When I do not handle the resize, the parent window is resized and the child windows stay in the same place.

I have know that this has to be in the message of WM_SIZE but I do not know how to handle the rest from there. I have tried the MoveWindow() and UpdateWindow() function but it didn't seem to work for me.

I have been trying to get this window child to resize correctly:
`hName = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 200, 50, 98, 38, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);`. So far nothing has worked. Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: but look like you even not try move/resize childs. you not call `MoveWindow` for childs. but better use `BeginDeferWindowPos` + `DeferWindowPos` + `EndDeferWindowPos`

Comment: MoveWndow is known to work correctly. Presumably your code is deficient in some way. You'll want to show your code if you want help with it.

Comment: So with the MoveWindow function I was confused on how to get the relative position of the child window to the parent window. That was the part I was confused about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a global `RECT` to storage the left, top, width and height of Edit control(`RECT editSize = { 100, 50 , 100, 100 }`) .
In `WM_SIZE` message, call `EnumChildWindows`, resize my child windows in `EnumChildProc`

```
case WM_SIZE:
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
        EnumChildWindows(hWnd, EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)&rcClient);
        return 0;
```

`EnumChildProc`:

```
#define ID_Edit1  200 

...

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwndChild, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int idChild;
    idChild = GetWindowLong(hwndChild, GWL_ID);
    LPRECT rcParent;
    rcParent = (LPRECT)lParam;

    if (idChild == ID_Edit1) {

        //Calculate the change ratio
        double cxRate = rcParent->right * 1.0 / 884; //884 is width of client area
        double cyRate = rcParent->bottom * 1.0 / 641; //641 is height of client area

        LONG newRight = editSize.left * cxRate;
        LONG newTop = editSize.top * cyRate;
        LONG newWidth = editSize.right * cxRate;
        LONG newHeight = editSize.bottom * cyRate;

        MoveWindow(hwndChild, newRight, newTop, newWidth, newHeight, TRUE);

        // Make sure the child window is visible. 
        ShowWindow(hwndChild, SW_SHOW);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. When I changed the size of the parent window, the children didn't move along with it.
Here are the global:
```#define ID_Edit1  200
RECT editSize = { 100, 50 , 100, 100 };
RECT rcClient;```

The WM_Size: ```case WM_SIZE:
  GetClientRect(hName, &rcClient);
  EnumChildWindows(hName, EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)&rcClient);
  break;```
The EnumChildProc had no change in code. What should I do?

Comment: The size of my main window is `(100, 100, 900, 700)`.

Comment: I add two screenshots.Use the global variable to store the original size. When the size of the main window changes, calculate the rate of change, multiply the original size of the control, get the changed size, and change the size using MoveWindow.

Comment: I have done that and it still doesn't work. Here is some images. [WM_SIZE](https://gyazo.com/ff686fa81f6c49e70d4648a2125cdbd8) [Global](https://gyazo.com/79b1cf4beaaa520b073893379600eeb6) [Enum](https://gyazo.com/bd2b16fad0e0d0216fd2253cb90aadf9)

Comment: It must be somewhere issue.My main windows:`hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      100, 100, 900, 700, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);`, create edit control`case WM_CREATE:
  // Create three invisible child windows. 
  editControl = CreateWindowEx(0,
    L"Edit",
    (LPCTSTR)NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE,
       editSize.left, editSize.top, editSize.right, editSize.bottom,
    hWnd,
      (HMENU)(int)ID_Edit1,
    hInst,
    NULL);
   
  return 0;`. Could you show me your whole code?

Comment: I've upload [my demo](https://github.com/Jeffrey-shao-code/testDemo) in github.Please check it.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! This helped me a lot!!