# Weird wingdi painting problem; After about 30 seconds the window will no longer be updated

Tags: c, winapi

I have always been pretty familiar with C. I chose to use C with Visual Studio 2017 to make a small windows game for a midterm project in my AP computer science class this year. It is of course using winapi, but I am using the wingdi library to render the simple 2d game; using wingdi might not be the best method, but in the interest of time and simplicity I decided to do so, since I really only have a couple of days to finish this.

The game loads environments in which you are able to navigate a character around them, and as I finished up testing the simple 2d collision physics I implemented for the character movement and walls, I realized that when I left the application running in debug mode, it seemed to have stopped painting the green border walls for the Demo environment, shortly after that, the small rectangle for the character hitbox disappeared, and when I resized the window, the whole top-bar disappeared and was replaced with the tan background color that I set the window's hbrBackground to.

I read a post about someone who also had trouble with wingdi painting, and people suggested that it was a memory leak, but my application is considerably small, and I really do not see anything that could be a memory leak in my code to my knowledge...

I set a timer with USER_TIMER_MINIMUM, to call InvalidateRect so that the screen could be continuously updated, since the character needs to be able to be moved around.

In WM_PAINT I was sure to start with BeginPaint, and close with EndPaint. Here is my code that actually deals with wingdi:

source.c:

```
int DEMO_ROOM[] = 
{
    0, 0, 500, 10,
    0, 0, 10, 500,
    490, 0, 500, 500,
    0, 490, 500, 500
};



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        RunTrack1();
        TITLE_IMAGE = LoadBitmapA(PROGRAM, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1));

        char_pos.X = 250;
        char_pos.Y = 250;

        SetTimer(hwnd, 1, USER_TIMER_MINIMUM, NULL);

        break;
    case WM_TIMER:

        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);

        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        LoadRoom(hdc, hwnd, &DEMO_ROOM, sizeof(DEMO_ROOM));
        LoadChar(hdc, hwnd, char_pos.X, char_pos.Y);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case 0x57: //W
            MoveChar
            (
                &char_pos,
                char_pos.X,
                char_pos.Y - 5,
                &DEMO_ROOM,
                sizeof(DEMO_ROOM)
            );
            break;
        case 0x41: //A
            MoveChar
            (
                &char_pos,
                char_pos.X - 5,
                char_pos.Y,
                &DEMO_ROOM,
                sizeof(DEMO_ROOM)
            );
            break;
        case 0x53: //S
            MoveChar
            (
                &char_pos,
                char_pos.X,
                char_pos.Y + 5,
                &DEMO_ROOM,
                sizeof(DEMO_ROOM)
            );
            break;
        case 0x44: //D
            MoveChar
            (
                &char_pos,
                char_pos.X + 5,
                char_pos.Y,
                &DEMO_ROOM,
                sizeof(DEMO_ROOM)
            );
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_KEYUP:

        break;
    case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
        ((LPMINMAXINFO)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2;
        ((LPMINMAXINFO)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2;
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        //KillTimer(hwnd, 1);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

GameLibrary.h:

```
GameCoordinate GameSpaceToWindowSpace(HWND hwnd, int X, int Y, int MAX)
{
    RECT w;
    GameCoordinate pos;
    if (GetWindowRect(hwnd, &w))
    {
        int width = (w.right - w.left) - 20;
        int height = (w.bottom - w.top) - 43;
        float XRatio = (float)X / (float)MAX;
        float YRatio = (float)Y / (float)MAX;
        float XWindowPos = XRatio * (float)width;
        float YWindowPos = YRatio * (float)height;
        pos.X = (int)XWindowPos;
        pos.Y = (int)YWindowPos;
    }
    return pos;
}

void LoadRoom(HDC hdc, HWND hwnd, int * ROOM_DATA, unsigned int R_SIZE)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (R_SIZE / 16); i++)
    {
        int left = ROOM_DATA[i * 4];
        int top = ROOM_DATA[(i * 4) + 1];
        int right = ROOM_DATA[(i * 4) + 2];
        int bottom = ROOM_DATA[(i * 4) + 3];
        GameCoordinate C1 = GameSpaceToWindowSpace(hwnd, left, top, 500);
        GameCoordinate C2 = GameSpaceToWindowSpace(hwnd, right, bottom, 500);
        RECT obj;
        obj.left = C1.X;
        obj.top = C1.Y;
        obj.right = C2.X;
        obj.bottom = C2.Y;
        FillRect(hdc, &obj, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(22, 110, 18)));
    }
}

void LoadChar(HDC hdc, HWND hwnd, int x, int y)
{
    GameCoordinate windowPos = GameSpaceToWindowSpace(hwnd, x, y, 500);
    Rectangle(hdc, windowPos.X - 1, windowPos.Y - 1, windowPos.X + 1, windowPos.Y + 1);
}
```

It was not really necessary for me to include the function GameSpaceToWindowSpace in the code, but I decided to, just to avoid any confusion about my small custom coordinate system.

This code is pretty much my game so far, excluding two collision functions, my WinMain, and a couple global variables.

Here is an image of what the window is intended to look like, the small dot with the blue circle around it represents the coordinate of the character, and the green walls around the window are supposed to be border walls to help me test collisions:

[image]

Here is what happens to the window after about 30 seconds:

[image]

Sometimes the character rectangle disappears as well, and this last picture is a representation to show that for some reason it will no longer paint, or refresh the window; as I had the window maximized, and then minimized it to show that the border rectangles did not update their size and position with the window:

[image]

To conclude, I am definitely new to wingdi, but with my familiarity with winapi, I figured it would be my best bet to creating some simple graphics for a simple 2d game in a short amount of time. However when my application runs for a slightly extended amount of time, the painting process seems to fail, and it can no longer update and refresh the window contents. I am really not sure what the problem is here, nor do I know how I could properly address it. I don't think that it is a memory leak due to the small size of my program at the moment, however I am also pretty much a noob with wingdi, so I could be very wrong and it may very well be a memory leak, but either way I do not know how to go about fixing this problem, and would really appreciate some more experienced insight on the problem.

Thank you all for your time and expertise.

Comment: You might want to read the docs for `CreateSolidBrush` and see what you need to do when you're done with it. You might also consider just creating one and using it multiple times.

Comment: make sure you're not leaking any object in the main loop (in LoadRoom or LoadChar functions): pen, brushes, etc. every object you create in there must also be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running out of GDI resources. `LoadRoom` is called for every `WM_PAINT` cycle. Inside that function, this is the offending code:

```cpp
FillRect(hdc, &obj, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(22, 110, 18)));
```

Note that [CreateSolidBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createsolidbrush) returns a resource you are required to manage:

> When you no longer need the `HBRUSH` object, call the [DeleteObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject) function to delete it.

You never do that, and eventually run out of GDI resources. A simple fix would be the following:

```cpp
HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(22, 110, 18));
FillRect(hdc, &obj, hbr);
DeleteObject(hbr);
```

It's still wasteful to create a brush on every paint cycle, but there is no leak anymore. If you want to be conservative, you can allocate the brush when initializing your rendering resources, and re-use that.

A C++ solution to the problem would be to use the [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) technique. A useful application can be found in Microsoft's [Windows Implementation Libraries (WIL)](https://github.com/microsoft/wil). The pre-built type to address this issue is [unique_hbrush](https://github.com/Microsoft/wil/wiki/RAII-resource-wrappers#available-unique_any-handle-types).

---

A simple way to diagnose issues like that is to use Task Manager. You can switch to the *Details* tab, and enable the column *GDI Objects*. If you see a constant increase in that number, you almost certainly have a resource leak.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the leaking memory mentioned in the comments, you also need to pay attention to the flickering problem and the coordinate problem after maximizing the window.

**What is flickering?**

Every time you receive a `WM_PAINT` message, you know that you have a nice fresh canvas to draw on. However, drawing a window twice (once with `WM_ERASEBKGND`, once again with `WM_PAINT`) will cause the window to badly flicker.

Beacuse `WM_ERASEBKGND` message is sent to a window when it’s background needs to be erased.

**How do we avoid erasing the background of a window?**

There are two methods.

- Set the window’s background brush to NULL. (Set the hbrBackground
  member of the WNDCLASS structure to zero when you register the window
  class).
- Return non-zero in the WM_ERASEBKGND message handler.

  Code:

  ```
  case WM_ERASEBKGND:
      return 1;
  ```

Of course, a common method to completely eliminate flickering windows is to use a technique called double-buffering. This basic idea is to draw a window’s contents into an off-screen buffer, and then transfer this buffer to the screen in one fell-swoop (using [BitBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt)). This is a pretty good way to reduce flicker, but is often overused, especially by programmers who don’t really understand how get efficient drawing working.

You can refer [this link](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/win32/flicker-free-drawing#) for more details.

**Due to the coordinate problem:**

Here is a example you can refer:

[How can I handle the resize of children windows when the parent windows is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676439/how-can-i-handle-the-resize-of-children-windows-when-the-parent-windows-is-resiz/58688756#58688756)